# Handling JavaScript script-tag widgets within ember.js applications

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Handlebars templates in ember.js applications are within "script" tags. Third party widgets, ads, and whatnot often is another "script" which document.writes something in the place it's inserted.

Script withing a script tag will not work, so is there a way to handle then within ember applications?

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of writing maintainable, DRY code, an Ember app of any real size or significance should be built using a build tool like [ember-cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) or [brunch](https://github.com/gcollazo/brunch-with-ember-reloaded). These build tools will compile the application files (including templates and vendor files) from multiple directories. I'll cover those, then I'll cover a couple of ways in which you can include widgets/scripts without a build tool.

**1)** Whilst the Ember Guides show you how to define your templates using `script` tags, that's not an efficient or effective way to manage your application's templates (unless you're building an app for learning purposes or a JSbin demo, etc, when you need to put everything inside a single file). Build tools like those mentioned above use resolvers to watch your file directories and compile the templates to the `Ember.TEMPLATES` object, which is where your application would access them anyway.

These build tools usually have separate directories in which to place your vendor files (e.g. third-part widgets), which will usually be watched for changes and compiled into a `vendor.js` file that is included in your `index.html` page. You can also use dependency management tools like NPM and Bower to streamline this process. In both situations, the plugin methods will be accessible throughout your application.

**2)** If you *really* don't want to use a build tool then just include the `script` tags on your `index.html` page just before the closing `body` tag and any methods will be accessible on the `window` object inside your application. This is obviously not effective if you're trying to place a widget like a social sharing button in a specific place on the page.

**3)** Another approach when you're not using a build tool would be to run the `$.getScript()` method  ([see here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)) inside a view or component on the `didInsertElement` event. This is probably the best way to include widget-like scripts at particular places in your template. Inside the view you can use `this.$().find('.some-selector')` to target specific elements inside the template or `this.$()` to target the view's element itself.

More info:

- [Templates in Ember CLI](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#resolving-from-template-helpers)

Comment: I have Django at the backend and using it template magic I have multiple *.handlebars files that are inserter into the primary template into every ember template "script". For development there are multiple files but in the end ember gets one big file.

I'll probably will have to use getScript for now, but it looks like I need to manage those templates differently.